# Why does my css media query not work on interior pages?

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I am using media queries to set breakpoints that adjust styling for html elements based on min and max screen sizes. It is working flawlessly on my index page, but the interior pages which are linked to the same style sheet and are using shared classes are not adjusting.

Here is one of my working media queries which functions as a way to collapse header div into a nav menu:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  input.navigate   { display: none; }
  img.googlepic {display: none;}
  img.navpic {display: none;}
  nav select { display: inline;}
}
```

Here is the relevant code from index.html:

```
<div class="header">

    <a href="index.html#pagetop"><input class="navigate" type="button" value="Home"></a>
    <a href="demo.html"><input class="navigate" type="button" value="Learn More"></a>
    <a href="aboutus.html"><input class="navigate" type="button" value="About Us"></a>
    <a href="blog.html"><input class="navigate" type="button" value="RMS News"></a>
    <a href="index.html#contactus"><input class="navigate" type="button" value="Contact Us"></a>
    <img class="googlepic" src="images/chrome.png">
    <img class="navpic" src="images/icx.png">

<nav>
    <select> 
    <option value="" selected="selected">Nav</option> 
    <a href="index.html#pagetop"><option value="index.html#pagetop">Home</option></a>
    <a href="demo.html"><option value="demo.html">Learn More</option></a>
    <a href="aboutus.html"><option value="aboutus.html">The RMS Team</option></a>
    <a href="blog.html"><option value="blog.html">Blog</option></a>
    <a href="index.html#contactus"><option value="index.html#contactus">Contact Us</option></a>
    </select> 

</nav>
</div>
```

The same exact code is copied and pasted into the interior pages of my site, but the media queries do not affect them.

Comment: Can you inspect interior page elements in browser developer tools and see if the CSS rules are being loaded or not.

Comment: Maybe the interior pages *aren’t* linked to the same style sheet. Can you provide your link tag?

Comment: Figure it out... I forgot to set the viewport meta tags outside of the index file. Glubey, your response made me realize my error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The meta tags for viewport were not set on interior pages.

```
<meta name="viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```